# Implementing an interface declared in C# from C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Say I have a C# interface called `IMyInterface` defined as follows:

```
// C# code
public interface IMyInterface
{
  void Foo(string value);
  string MyProperty { get; }
}
```

Assume I also have a C++/CLI class, `MyConcreteClass`, that implements this interface and whose header is declared as follows:

```
// C++/CLI header file
ref class MyConcreteClass : IMyInterface
{
public:

};
```

How does one implement the method `Foo` and the property `MyProperty` in the C++/CLI header?

My attempt results in the following compile error:

> error C3766: 'MyConcreteClass' must
>   provide an implementation for the
>   interface method 'void
>   IMyInterface::Foo(System::String^
>   value)'

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
public ref class MyConcreteClass : public IMyInterface
{
 public:
  virtual void __clrcall Foo(String^ value) sealed;  

  virtual property String^ __clrcall MyProperty 
         { String^ get() sealed { String::Empty; } }
};
```

Interfaces need to be defined as virtual.  Also note the "public IMy.." after the class decleration, it's a slighly different syntax than C#.

If you can, seal the interface members to improve performance, the compiler will be able to bind these methods more tightly than a typical virtual members.

Hope that helps ;)

I did not compile it but looks good to me... Oh and also, defining your methods as __clrcall eliminates dangers of double thunk performance penalties.

**edit**
the correct syntax for a property is:

```
public ref class MyConcreteClass : public IMyInterface
{
 public:
  virtual property String^ MyProperty 
  {
    String^ get() sealed { return String::Empty; };
    void set( String^ s ) sealed { };
  }
};
```

or, when putting the definition in the source file:

```
public ref class MyConcreteClass : public IMyInterface
{
 public:
  virtual property String^ MyProperty 
  {
    String^ get() sealed;
    void set( String^ s ) sealed;
  }
};

String^ MyConcreteClass::MyProperty::get()
{
  return String::Empty;
}

void MyConcreteClass::MyProperty::set( String^ )
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Does the MyProperty declaration not require the 'property' keyword? Eg... virtual property String^ MyProperty { String^ __clrcall get() sealed { return String::Empty; } }

Comment: Thanks Simon, I must of been cross eye'd from this marathon 30hour coding stretch!! =)

Comment: since this is one of the first hits in google, I edited the answer with the correct syntax for properties, which is kinda tricky.

Comment: @stijn I don't believe the keyword `sealed` is required just for the syntax, or is it?

Comment: @herzbube indeed it's not (well unless you want the property to be sealed), I included it because the original answer had it already