# Call methods from Managed C++ dll object

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, object, .net-assembly

I load my dll in C# with

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath); // late binding
Type classType = assembly.GetType("Namespace.Classname"); 
object readerInterface = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
```

but how can I access to my methods/members in readerInterface without

```
type.InvokeMember("Methodname", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |             
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, readerInterface, null);
```

--> in form of readerInterface.write(); ???

Thank you very much!

greets leon22

Comment: 3.5 .net on Visual Studio 2008

Comment: If you have a C++/CLI DLL, why not just reference the DLL from your C# project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that you can't just reference the assembly in your project C#... have the C++/CLI object implement an interface and cast it to that interface, then just use it as normal.

1) declare your interface in C# using whatever methods are appropriate

```
public interface IFoo
{
    SomeMethod()
}
```

2) [Implement the interface on your C++/CLI object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880984/implementing-an-interface-declared-in-c-from-c-cli)

3) cast the object that you created through reflection to that interface

```
object readerInterface = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
IFoo myFoo = readerInterfces as IFoo;
```

Comment: Ok. Have you an example how the interface looks like?

Comment: @leon22 added some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In c# 3 you must use reflection or have the object implement a known interface.

In C# 4 you can use dynamic instead. (will still use reflection but with nicer syntax)