# Use a C# interface in C++ or use a C++ interface in C#

Tags: c#, c++, interface, clr

I'm developping a solution where I have an Interface (in C#) that has to be used by a C++ solution and a C# solution.
I would like to know:

What is the best way to achieve this between:

- A C# interface that I use in my C++ project
- A C++ interface that I'll use in my C# project

Also could you indicate me how I should proceed for the best solution?

Comment: Have you looked at C++ .Net.  You can create a .Net interface and implement it in C++, C# VB.Net or any other .Net language.

Comment: You could also look at COM Type Libraries to define your interface and implement them in any COM compatible language.

Comment: Refer to the [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/implementing-csharp-interfaces-in-cplusplus) link and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880984/implementing-an-interface-declared-in-c-sharp-from-c-cli) post.

Comment: @Jaguar your first link is really helpfull!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean managed c++?

In case of managed c++ it is easy to do, just put interface in separate project(dll) and reference it from c#

Things become difficult if you want to do the same with not-managed c++

Than you would need to use [COM](http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx),[PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) or some kind of service/socket comunication

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using managed C++.
So I created a C# interface and I referenced it in my C++  project.
When I implemented my Interface I had to put the Keyword "virtual" before my method and everything seems to to be working fine!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see from your last comment that you are using managed C++, so therefore it is straight forward, but I will leave this reply.

C# (building COM class):

```
[Guid("69432320-04B6-3233-928F-FD8583232C880")]
public interface MyInterface
{
   [DispId(1)]
   void Method1 (string name);
}

MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface )new ConcreateClassImplementingInterface ();
```

Native C++:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("69432320-04B6-3233-928F-FD8583232C880") //note: same guid
{
  public:
     virtual Method1 (BSTR name);
}
```

That is by no means complete, but hopefully gives you an idea of whats involved and some key terms.