# Detect Communication activity c#

Tags: c#, windows

Is it possible from c# maybe via WMI to detect communication activity?

Windows will adjust your volume when you have an incoming call but I would like todo more.

[image: Communications settings in Windows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate the Core Audio API's for Windows.

They have an article on Custom Ducking behaviour [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd940517(v=vs.85).aspx)

Specifically, there's a page on capturing ducking events [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd940395(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I will look at that in more detail.. its given me more search terms to Google, I didn't know it was called Ducking. Its not quite c# so I will keep the Q unanswered for now and hope for some c# examples to pop up.

Comment: You essentially need to put 2 and 2 together - you can see the API calls/events etc that they capture, and then use those methods and calls from C#.  There's plenty of resources available for importing DLLs and calling those functions from within C#.

Answer (score 1):

The ducking notification API on Windows is implemented on the header `Audiopolicy.h`  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_coreaudio/ search for duck on that page). For your `C#` application to control this behavior, you would need to write a interface between `C#` and the `C++` Windows API, which uses the `Audiopolicy.h` header ([Use a C# interface in C++ or use a C++ interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898602/use-a-c-sharp-interface-in-c-or-use-a-c-interface-in-c-sharp)).