# 'MyClass' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'SomeMethod'

Tags: c++-cx, uwp

I am new to windows programming. I have googled this issue but couldn't solve my problem for four to five days.

> 'SpecialistMetro::SampleData::AdministrationItem' must provide an implementation for the interface method 'Windows::Foundation::EventRegistrationToken Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged::add(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler ^)'

Found some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880984/implementing-an-interface-declared-in-c-sharp-from-c-cli) but no use.

My code for AdministrationItem.h:

```
namespace SpecialistMetro
{
namespace SampleData
{
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    [Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
    public ref class AdministrationItem : public Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject, public History::IDataSample
    {
    private:
        Platform::String^ _State;
    public:
        virtual Platform::String^ getCustomerId();
        virtual Platform::String^ getSessionId();
        virtual property Platform::String^ State
        {
            Platform::String^ get();
            void set(Platform::String^ value);
        }
        virtual property Platform::String^ ClientName;
        virtual property Platform::String^ OrganizationName;
        virtual property Platform::String^ ClientEmail;
        virtual property Platform::String^ ClientPhoneNumber;
        virtual property Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush^ Color;
        virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
        virtual void OnPropertyChanged(Platform::String^ propertyName);
        virtual void UpdateConnectionInfo();
    };
}
}
```

Code for AdministrationItem.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "AdministrationItem.h"

using namespace SpecialistMetro::SampleData;

Platform::String^ AdministrationItem::State::get()
{
    return _State;
}

void AdministrationItem::State::set(Platform::String^ value)
{
    _State = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("State");
}

Platform::String^ AdministrationItem::getCustomerId()
{
    return "";
}

Platform::String^ AdministrationItem::getSessionId()
{
    return "";
}

void AdministrationItem::UpdateConnectionInfo()
{
}

void AdministrationItem::OnPropertyChanged(Platform::String^ propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: could you please add your code

Comment: code added in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The message kind of explains it. AdministrationItem is missing PropertyChangedEventHandler, which is needed because you have the `Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable` attribute on your AdministrationItem class.

```
event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
```

Read more [about the BindableAttribute here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindableattribute.aspx).

Learn how to add the event in this blog post: [Data Binding and C++/CX: INotifyPropertyChanged](https://phsucharee.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/data-binding-and-ccx-inotifypropertychanged/)

Comment: Haven't i done that already??
`virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;` by doing this.

Comment: I have done all the things already that are explained in the blog. but still no use.

Comment: See my implementation class.