# C++/CLI Implementing a C# Interface

Tags: c#, interface, c++-cli

I have a C# interface which looks like this:

```
public interface ITdcConnector
{
    void Close(uint);
    void FetchRequestAsync(ManagedFetchRequest);
    UInt32 Open(String, Action<uint, ManagedFetchResponse>, out Int64);
}
```

I am trying to implement in C++/CLI like this:

```
public ref class MockTdcConnector : public ITdcConnector
{
public:
    virtual Void Close(UInt32);
    Void FetchRequestAsync(ManagedFetchRequest);
    UInt32 Open(String, Action<UInt32, ManagedFetchResponse^>^,
      [System::Runtime::InteropServices::Out] Int64%);
};
```

IntelliSense is giving me grief on the `Open()` method. It tells me: `IntelliSense: class fails to implement interface member function "ITdcConnector::Open"`

I've looked at a [few relevant examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880984/implementing-an-interface-declared-in-c-sharp-from-c-cli) on implementing C# classes in C++/CLI, but no luck. Any idea on how to get the C++/cli method signature to look like the C# method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I didn't see this until just now. I started typing the name of the C# method in the C++/cli class and IntelliSence showed the method signature it was expecting. I just needed some more `^`s and `virtual`s.

Here is what I ended up using, for future reference:

```
public ref class MockTdcConnector : public ITdcConnector
{
public:
    virtual Void Close(UInt32);
    virtual Void FetchRequestAsync(ManagedFetchRequest^);
    virtual UInt32 Open(String^, Action<UInt32, ManagedFetchResponse^>^
      [Runtime::InteropServices::Out] Int64%);
};
```