# Inherit from C# interface to class in C++/CLI project

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

My C++/CLI dll project refers to a C# dll. I'm able to use all the classes defined in the refered dll, but I'm unsure how to handle Interfaces.

By reading other questions online, I believe I should be able to create a class which inherits from the interface.

If the interface is called `IMeshData` and I define a class `MeshData`, isn't this correct?:

```
public ref class MeshData : IMeshData{

     //Here I should be able to implement my own functions which can access the interface function, or overload them.

}
```

In Visual Studio, if I do the above, I will get an error on `MeshData` stating:

> Error: class fails to implement interface function "IMeshData::NodeById" (declared in (...).dll)

The function `IMeshData::NodeById` is defined as:

```
INode IMeshData.NodeById(Int32 nodeId)
```

Where `INode` is a different interface.

Does that error mean that this function `NodeById`, can for reason not be implemented, and therefor I'm cannot inherit any functions?

How would I implement this function (which I do not need), so that this error will be resolved?

I do not have access the source of the refered dll.

Comment: Interfaces are *implemented*, not *inherited*. By marking a class as implementing an interface you are stating that your class provides all of the functions and properties specified in the interface. Therefore the error you are seeing is telling you that the interface requires your class to provide a `NodeById` function which you are not yet providing.

Comment: An interface declares methods or properties which must be implemented by the class which is implementing it. So, you either need to learn what that paricular method is used for and write a solution in your class which will implement that method or else just declare it and do nothing inside the method.

Comment: @RyanWilson So in my case, I know that this function will return another interface, and I know the parameters of the function. I do not need that exact function, but I also don't know how I can re-declare it to do nothing.

Comment: @remi Just declare the method in your class with the exact name and parameters that are declared in the interface, then if its void don't fill in the method body, else if you don't need to use it, just return a default value of type T

Comment: Thanks @RyanWilson , I tried re-implementing the function, but I'm not sure what you mean about returning a default value of type T. I've slightly updated the question, would you care to give me an example?

Comment: It is not correct terminology to say _"re-implementing the function"_.  You are not _"`re`-implementing"_ anything. You are not overriding a base class.  You instead need to implement the _interface_ (or _realise_ in UML speak).

Comment: @remi Return a default INode value from the method. Type T is used in generics to basically say that this method will return an object of the type declared, so in your case it is type INode.

Comment: You can *implement* it to do nothing with `throw gcnew NotImplementedException;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing an interface declared in C# from C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880984/implementing-an-interface-declared-in-c-sharp-from-c-cli)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed it, with courtesy to the comments above:

```
public ref class MeshData : IMeshData{
    public:
         virtual INode^ NodeById(int){throw gcnew NotImplementedException;}
}
```

(That solved the error message I mentioned in the question, but now it is telling me the same thing about another function. So this will probably have to be repeated.)